# Div Width 100% not working when resizing of browser

Tags: html, css, width

Basically, my 100% width Div wrappers aren't working right when I re-size the browser. When you re-size the browser smaller than what the page design is, I get a horizontal scroll bar and it's not actually spanning full width. It's like it's just cutting off at some point.

Here is the link : [Website Link](http://www.officiallymade.com/)

I've tried to fix this but it's just really confusing me why this is happening. Can anyone shed some light on this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Mark

Comment: You have absolute (px) widths on some of your elements.

Comment: I see a lot of `floating` divs, which might be the problem. Even your basic layout is floating, while you should be able to create a centered layout without floating divs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out! I set width: 100% to min-width: 100% and that fixes the issues.

Comment: to which element have you added the width /min-width ? Have you done anything special  in <body> for css or for that matter for <html> or let viewport support ...

Comment: Can you set `min-width` to a percentage?

Answer (score 1):

Your .wrap div has a fixed width of 1050px which is forcing the minimum width of the page to also be 1050px. This is why you are seeing scrollbars when the browser window is less than 1050px wide.

```
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1050px;
}
```

However, there is a reason why this width is fixed, because the `margin:0 auto;` requires a fixed width div in order to centre the content.

If you would like your design to scale down for narrower screens, then I suggest that you look at using CSS Media Queries to create alternative rules for different browser/device widths.

Try resising this [demo](http://css-tricks.com/examples/MediaQueriesSidebar/) to see if it does what you want, and if so, work through the [tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/).

[Smashing Magazine](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) also has a good media queries tutorial, especially if you are looking for alternative layouts for mobile devices.